# How to check if compound proposition is contradiction (is always false)?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I know how to check compound proposition if it is *tautology* with `TautologyQ[]`. But I have not found any function that can check if the compound proposition is *contradiction* (is always false). Is there any similar way (like with *tautology*, without generating truth tables) to check if a compound proposition is a *contradiction* or not?

For example, how can I check if compound proposition `p && !p` is a contradiction or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The converse of *tautology* (negation of *tautology*) is a *contradiction*. More about it here:  proofwiki.org/wiki/Contradiction_is_Negation_of_Tautology

So to find out if the proposition is a *contradiction* we can negate the proposition and after check the result if it is the *tautology*. If the output is `True` it means that the proposition is *contradiction* because as we mentioned above the negation of a *contradiction* is a *tautology*. If the output is `False`, that means that the proposition is not *contradiction* and it can be *tautology* or *contingency*.

For example, if we want to check if `p && ! p` is a *contradiction* (which it is) we use code:

```
TautologyQ[Not[p && ! p], {p}]
```

Output:

> True

Comment: Does this checks "if the proposition is a contradiction" or it checks "if the proposition is not a tautology"?

Comment: It checks that the converse of the propositions is a tautology. In my understanding, that means that the proposition is contradiction.

Comment: I think you are right: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Contradiction_is_Negation_of_Tautology

Comment: If f is a boolean-valued function, then f(x1, x2, ..., xn) is true for all possible values of the arguments if and only if ¬f(x1, x2, ..., xn) is false for all possible values of the arguments. Hence, Henrik's approach is valid.

Comment: I edited the answer and added more clarification and information from comments. Is it ok?

Comment: @vasili111 More info is always good. ^^

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think I also found another way. Can you please take a look at it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180518/11639

Answer (score 7):

```
Resolve[Exists[p, p && ! p == True]]
```

(*

False

*)

You can interpret this result as:  "There does not exist any `p` such that the statement `p && !p` is `True`.

Background example:

```
Resolve[Exists[{p, q}, (p && ! p == True || q == True)]]
```

(*

True

*)

You can interpret this result to say:

It is true that there exists some `p` and `q` such that both `p` and `!p` are `True` OR `q` is `True`.  The key claus here is the OR.  Certainly there exists some `q` for which `q` is `True`.

Comment: In your example, I can substitute `p, p && ! p` for any other compound proposition to check for a contradiction, right? For example, for `a||b`There sould be `Resolve[Exists[a, b, a && b == True]]` ?

Comment: Also if `False` it means contradiction and if `True` it means that it is not a contradiction?

Comment: `False` in my solution example means there does not exist any `p` such that `p` and `not p` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I also found another way:

"In a complete logic, a formula is contradictory if and only if it is unsatisfiable". [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction)

In that case, we can check if the proposition is *satisfiable* and after *negate* the result. If the output is `True`that means that the original statement was *unsatisfiable* which also means that it was *contradiction*. If the output was `False` it means that the result was *satisfiable*, which means that it was *tautology* or *contingency*.

---

For example, lets check if `p && !p` is *contradiction*:

```
Not[SatisfiableQ[p && ! p, {p}]]
```

output:

> True

It means that `p && !p` is *contradiction*.

---

Lets check if `p || ! p` is *contradiction*:

```
Not[SatisfiableQ[p || ! p, {p}]]
```

output:

> False

It means that `p || ! p` is **not** *contradiction*. The output does not say that but it is *tautology*.

---

Lets check if `p && q` is *contradiction*:

```
Not[SatisfiableQ[p && q, {p, q}]]
```

output:

> False

It means that `p && q` is **not** *contradiction*. The output does not say that but it is *contingency*.

Comment: That makes sense because of: $\neg (\exists p \colon \text{$A(p)$ is true})$ is equivalent to $(\forall p \colon \neg (\text{$A(p)$ is true}))$. `SatisfiableQ` is essentially the $\exists$-quantor.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you.